# Does adding a Viewcontroller to Navigation controller increments the retain Count?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Please do not close this question  or mention it as duplicate.

I want your help in confirming my  understanding.

This is applicable in VIew Controllers added to Navigation Controller.
A guy [RayNewbie](https://discussions.apple.com/people/RayNewbie) in this [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2219375?start=15&tstart=0) mentions that if we retain the instance of an View Controller, their retain count would become +2 and when we pop it, the retain count is reduced by 1. So the dealloc never gets called.

Is his argument correct?

If it is correct, does they hold true in the below case:

Right now I have a two VCs as an iVar in AppDelegate class:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UserDetailsViewController *userdetailsVC;
@property (retain, nonatomic) PayDetailsViewController *paydetailsVC;

userdetailsVC = [[UserDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:kuserDetailsVC bundle:nil];

paydetailsVC = [[PayDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:kpayDetailsVC bundle:nil];
```

I synthesize the iVars in .m file.

Based on user's actions I set any of the above VC's to  the window's  root View controler.

```
-(void)method1{

 self.window.rootViewController = userdetailsVC;

}

-(void)method2{

 self.window.rootViewController = paydetailsVC;

}
```

Am I doing anything wrong here in the way I set the root view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, adding a view controller to a navigation controller adds the retain count. The navigation controller maintains an array of view controllers. When you add a view controller there, it gets added to this array. This array is the one used in pushViewController and popViewController calls.

That said, the way you are alloc'ing, is not recommended way. 
This is more appropriate:

```
UserDetailsViewController* u = [[UserDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:kuserDetailsVC bundle:nil];
self.userdetailsVC = u;
[u release];
PayDetailsViewController *p = [[PayDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:kpayDetailsVC bundle:nil];
self.paydetailsVC = p;
[p release];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How about the way I am assigning to self.window.rootViewController?

Comment: Is this the suggestion for any iVar in any of the View Controllers?

Comment: yes, that's the suggestion for any iVar that has property with retain. With your method, you were essentially making the retain count to goto 2 as the two iVars already had retains on them and then you were doing alloc on top of it.

Comment: regarding rootviewcontroller, if your motive is to go to the root of the stack of viewControllers in the navigation controller, do it like this: [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]